# How do I show the list on a different screen when Navigaor.pop used on the checkbox selection screen?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `CheckBox` items selection screen (opened when Navigator.push is triggered in a floating button) to check the items that I like and I want these items to show on the screen when Navigator.pop is used (when a floating button is tapped) to go back to the original screen from where it originated. But I'm not able to do it, I think list.map will be used here but have I'm able to implement it properly. Any help is really appreciated.

You can check the entire code [here](https://github.com/theyashjha/aioapp).

My code where I've problem:

```
// CheckBox Item Selection Screen!
class FavoriteList extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_FavoriteListState createState() => _FavoriteListState();
}

class _FavoriteListState extends State<FavoriteList> {

final Set _saved = Set();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Add to Favorites!'), centerTitle:  true, backgroundColor: Colors.red),
  // backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
  body: SafeArea(
          child: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 53,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return CheckboxListTile(
          activeColor: Colors.red,
          checkColor: Colors.white,
          value: _saved.contains(index),
             onChanged: (val) {
              setState(() {
              if(val == true){
                _saved.add(index);
              } else{
                _saved.remove(index);
              }
            });
          },
          title: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Image.asset('lib/images/${images[index]}'),
              SizedBox(width: 10,),
              Text(nameOfSite[index]),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
  ),
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(foregroundColor: Colors.red,
  child: Icon(Icons.check),
    onPressed: (){
      Navigator.pop(context, _saved); // Navigator.pop
    },
  ),
);
    }
   }
```

Here The original screen, to where I want to `return` the `_saved` list (i've used a Set as to avoid duplicates)

```
class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_SecondPageState createState() => _SecondPageState();
}


class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return 
   // if the `_saved` list contains something return the "_saved" list from 
   the CheckBox item selection screen, if not then 
    return  Column(
           mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
        Text(
           'Add Your Favorite Sites Here!❤',
           style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
           ),
           Container(
            child: Icon(Icons.favorite, size: 150, color: Colors.blue[100]),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 250),
            FloatingActionButton(
             onPressed: () {
               Navigator.push( //Navigator.push is here!
                  context,
                   MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => FavoriteList(),
                ),
              );
           },
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
          foregroundColor: Colors.blue,
         ),
        ],
       );
      }
   }
```

Comment: plz show where Navigator.push is called. You can utilize the return value, isn't it?

Comment: @LoL sorry, now i've edited the question you can have a look now! thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use Event_Bus to pass data between Screen.

This is lib

https://pub.dev/packages/event_bus

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you're poping, state of your previous page is not updated. So, return the result with selected items (from checkboxes) as a future while poping. Once you pop check whether you got any result on not and hence rebuild the ui with new state.

Answer (score 0):

You may utilize the return value of `push`

```
// _SecondPageState
FloatingActionButton(
  onPressed: () async {
    Set saved = await Navigator.push<Set>(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FavoriteList()),
    );
    setState(() {
      // do something
    });
  },
),
```

Comment: its not helping, the data is just not returning on the `SecondPage`

Answer (score 0):

`Navigator.push()` has a returned value, and you can pass in what you want while calling `Navigator.pop(`)

This is the main code you should notice:

in *SecondPage* class:

```
FloatingActionButton(
  onPressed: () async {
    final Set indices = await Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => FavoriteList(indices: _indices), // you may wanna passing in what you have checked.
      ),
    );

    if (indices != null) {
      // do what you want, like setState()
      setState(() {
        final List tempIndices = _indices;
        tempIndices.addAll(indices);
        _indices = tempIndices.toSet().toList();
      });
    }
  },
),
```

and in *FavoriteList* class:

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
  onPressed: () {
    Navigator.pop(context, _saved);
  },
),
```

And if you want to check the complete code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Navigator Data',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: SecondPage(),
    );
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _SecondPageState createState() => _SecondPageState();

}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {

  List _indices = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0, vertical: 75.0),
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Add Your Favorite Sites Here!',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 24.0,
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _indices.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Center(
                    child: Text(
                      '${_indices[index]}',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        fontSize: 24.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                final Set indices = await Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => FavoriteList(indices: _indices),
                  ),
                );

                if (indices != null) {
                  setState(() {
                    final List tempIndices = _indices;

                    tempIndices.addAll(indices);

                    _indices = tempIndices.toSet().toList();
                  });
                }
              },
              child: Icon(
                Icons.add,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              foregroundColor: Colors.blue,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}

class FavoriteList extends StatefulWidget {

  FavoriteList({
    Key key,
    this.indices,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final List indices;

  @override
  _FavoriteListState createState() => _FavoriteListState();

}

class _FavoriteListState extends State<FavoriteList> {

  final Set _saved = Set();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _saved.addAll(widget.indices);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Add to Favorites!'),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 53,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return CheckboxListTile(
              activeColor: Colors.red,
              checkColor: Colors.white,
              value: _saved.contains(index),
              onChanged: (val) {
                setState(() {
                  if (val == true) {
                    _saved.add(index);
                  } else {
                    _saved.remove(index);
                  }
                });
              },
              title: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('$index'),
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        foregroundColor: Colors.red,
        child: Icon(Icons.check),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pop(context, _saved);
        },
      ),
    );
  }

}
```